# Multimedia control with a multimedia keyboard in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, winmm

I have keyboards, as well as the keyboard built into my laptop, which have multimedia keys. One of the multimedia keys is of course pause/play and it's a function of the keyboard driver that can be assigned to other keys. When it's pushed, it will pause/play iTunes, Windows Media Player, etc. depending on what my "last active" media application is.

My question is, in C# how can I duplicate this functionality to be able to pause/play the system sound. I've looked through the API and the only thing that looked close were the winmm.dll waveOutPause and midiOutPause functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a class called [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3w7761b) in .NET that allows you to push keypresses to another application, but this doesn't (AFAIK) allow special keys to be sent.

So instead, I'd guess that you want the API function [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx).

There's a list of key-codes that includes the media keys [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731.aspx), so you can emulate keys like play/pause or volume controls.

**EDIT:** a possible alternative to using the API would be to *capture* whatever your multimedia keyboard sends when you press that key (in a WinForms or WPF app) and then see if you can replicate that keypress using the regular `SendKeys` implementation.

Comment: That answers the question I asked but there's a problem with it that makes it not work for what I need. If my media is already paused, I wouldn't just want to blindly send the play/pause key and start playing it before I lock the session. I need a way to either only send a command to pause the playback or a way to check if it's paused before sending the play/pause key.

Comment: As far as I know your choice is either "Play/Pause" or "Stop" - I don't think there's a specific global hotkey that differentiates play and pause.